# Rails Multiple 3rd Party API Requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails action that is very slow relative to the rest of my app.  It requests data from two different sources.  Once that data is pulled in from each source, I then loop through the data and compare with the current database, creating records if a similar record does not exist.

I have a few models below.  Song models generally have an RdioMeta or a SoundcloudMeta, each of which contains information pulled from Rdio and Soundcloud respectively.

def search
    @search = []

```
rdio_client  = RdioApi.new consumer_key: 'consumer_key', consumer_secret: 'consumer_secret'
rdio_results = rdio_client.search(query: params[:query], types: "track", count: 25)

sc_client  = Soundcloud.new client_id: 'client_id'
sc_results = sc_client.get('/tracks', q: "%#{params[:query]}%")

rdio_results.results.each do |result|
  song = Song.includes(:rdio_meta).where(name: result[:name], artist: result[:artist]).first_or_initialize do |song|
    rdio_meta = RdioMeta.new url: result[:key], duration: result[:duration]
    song.rdio_meta = rdio_meta
  end
  song.save
  @search << song
end

sc_results.each do |result|
  song = Song.includes(:soundcloud_meta).where(name: result[:title], artist: result[:user][:username]).first_or_initialize do |song|
    rdio_meta = SoundcloudMeta.new url: result[:stream_url], duration: result[:duration]
    song.rdio_meta = rdio_meta
  end
  song.save
  @search << song
end

render json: @search, root: 'songs'
```

end

My question is two-fold.  One, I'm used to JavaScript and async requests/promises, so what's the best way to approach something that could be asynchronous in Ruby/Rails?  Two, I did a massive refactoring of the original code, but I think it could be better.  Are there any optimizations I can do on the code?